# How to format hex to string?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to format the result into a 6-letter string, from this code:

```
Dim colorval as double=255.0
 String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}",
    Hex(colorVal Mod 256),   Hex((colorVal \ 256) Mod 256),   Hex(colorVal \ 65536))
```

but it returns "FF00", I am stuck at formatting `"0" to "00"`

How can i fix it?

Comment: Not directly related to the problem, but note my comment on the answers re the numeric constants you use for byte extraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Hex` method is already converting from a number to a string, so your call to `String.Format` is not actually using your [hexadecimal format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN#the-hexadecimal-x-format-specifier) of `X2` to enforce two chars in the string.

Therefore, just drop the call to `Hex`:

```
Dim colorval As Double = 255.0
Dim s As String = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", 
    CInt(colorval) Mod 256, (CInt(colorval) \ 256) Mod 256, CInt(colorval) \ 65536)
'value of s: "FF0000"
```

(Note that I added CInt to satisfy the compiler for `Option Strict On` since your color value was a `Double`. Also, at runtime, you would get a System.FormatException 'Format specifier was invalid' if you left the Mod operator returning a `Double` instead of an integer-based value.)

Comment: I'd recommend using hex-format numerical constants in the bit-twiddling part to make it a little more obvious what it's doing (and make it harder for an error to slip through).  I believe it would be &H100 and &H10000 replacing 256 and 65536.

Comment: Agreed.  The main question from OP was about formatting the strings, so my answer kept the bit-twiddling part the same as before to avoid confusion.  But you're right, and that part of the code can be improved.

Comment: Noted, and I also (upon re-review) see that you were just copying what the original code did there.

Comment: You should probably avoid CInt if you can. No sense in converting values if you can just change the type to fit what you actually need.

Comment: @Marie also agree.  Not sure why OP started with double for a value that really should be integer based.  I suppose I could also have used Convert.To instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `Hex` function [returns a string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/hex-function). Strings cannot be formatted with a length.

With that said your `colorval` variable is a double. [The `X` format is only supported by integers.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-hexadecimal-x-format-specifier)

With this in mind the following will work.

```vb
        Dim colorval as Integer = 255
        Dim result As String = String.Format("{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", colorVal Mod 256, (colorVal \ 256) Mod 256, colorVal \ 65536)
        Console.WriteLine(result)
```

Comment: Same comment as in the accepted answer re the numerical constants used for bit-twiddling.